# Testing Spring Controllers with JUnit

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, junit

How do I test a "resource" in a Spring Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{query}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String getResource(
        HttpServletRequest req, 
        HttpServletResponse res,
        @PathVariable String query,
        @RequestParam(value="param1", required = false) String param1,
        @RequestParam(value="param2", required = false) String param2) throws SomeException{
    return service.read(query);
}
```

And since I am developing with App Engine I have a JUnit scaffolding like this:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:service/client-config.xml" })
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class LocalDatastoreTest {
    private final LocalServiceTestHelper helper =
            new LocalServiceTestHelper(new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig());  

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        helper.setUp();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        helper.tearDown();
    }   

    @Test
    public void test() {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a test server up and running,
try using Spring RestTemplate in your test method

something like:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
String result = restTemplate.getForObject("YOUR_URL/{query}", String.class,"myQuery");
```

See more [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html).

If you don't have a server and need basic unit testing, try **mocking** one.
More info on another [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9138555/spring-framework-test-restful-web-service-controller-offline-i-e-no-server-n).

Or try using https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-test-mvc

Comment: I did use Google Http Client instead of RestTemplate as I can't seem to make it work with App Engine